# Trying to implement proportional navigation into Unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector

I tried using the equation for proportional navigation found in this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_navigation) but when I attempted to implement it in game, the missile often goes off in some direction opposite of my target.

I am not sure if this has to do with the way I normalized the acceleration to give it a maximum velocity, the precision of the coordinates, or my calculations but I have not been able to find the root of the issue.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
public class Missile : MonoBehaviour
{

    Target target;
    public Transform targetTransform;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float propCon = 3;
    Vector3 lastPos;
    Vector3 miLastPos;
    Vector3 velocity;

    void Start()
    {
        target = FindObjectOfType<Target>();
       lastPos = targetTransform.position; 
       miLastPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetVelocity = (targetTransform.position - lastPos) / Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 miVelocity = (transform.position - miLastPos) / Time.deltaTime;
       
        lastPos = targetTransform.position;
        miLastPos = transform.position;

        Vector3 range = targetTransform.position - transform.position;
        Vector3 relVelocity = targetVelocity - miVelocity;
        Vector3 rotVector = Vector3.Cross(range, relVelocity) / Vector3.Dot(range, range);
        Vector3 accNormal = propCon * Vector3.Cross(relVelocity, rotVector);
        Vector3 directionToTarget = accNormal.normalized;

        float distanceToTarget = range.magnitude;

        print ($"TV is: {targetVelocity} and lastPos {lastPos}\nmiVelocity is: {miVelocity} miPosition is: {miLastPos}");
        print ($"rotVector: {rotVector} and accNormal: {accNormal}\nrange: {range} and relVelocity: {relVelocity}");
        print ($"cross: {Vector3.Cross(range, relVelocity)} and dot: {Vector3.Dot(range, range)}");


        if (velocity.magnitude < speed)
        {
            velocity += (speed/10*directionToTarget);
        }

        if (distanceToTarget > 0.1f)
        {
            transform.Translate (velocity*Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was so free to edit your question: No images of code on StackOverflow! And I changed your code a little bit to improve readability, please confirm it still does basically the same, just removed some redundant `( )` and used string interpolation for the prints ;)

Comment: I apologize for responding late, but after a bit (several hours) of messing around and changing the movement relativity I got it to work! I'm not quite sure I understand why but thanks a ton for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of the calculation is correct (seems so at first glance comparing to the article you linked) I think the issues comes down to

```
transform.Translate(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Note that [`Transform.translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) by default uses **local space**. You are however working with world space vectors. If your missiles are anyhow rotated then your coordinate systems do not match anymore.

> If `relativeTo` is left out or set to `Space.Self` the movement is applied **relative to the transform's local axes**. (the x, y and z axes shown when selecting the object inside the Scene View [addition by me: and the [gizmos are set to Local](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html)].) If `relativeTo` is `Space.World` the movement is applied **relative to the world coordinate system.**

I think in general you rather want to use

```
transform.Translate (velocity * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

or also simply

```
transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
```

---

and then I would probably do this

```
miLastPos = transform.position;
```

**after** moving the object so the calculation should be more precise and not be based on the last frames delta movement.